# function inside class is not defined?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to check if the unique id generated is unique in the database because it's only 6 characters.

```
class Images(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=genid(), editable=False)
    def genid():
        uid = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6]
        if Images.objects.get(uid=uid).exists():
            uid = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6]
        return uid
```

but it's not working. it tells me genid is not defined, Images is not defined. how can I fix this?

thanks

Comment: The definition of `uid` refers to `genid()`, which hasn't been defined yet at that point in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At that time, `genid` is indeed not yet defined. Furthermore you should *not* call the function, since then it will take as default the result of the function. You should define this as:

```
class Images(models.Model):
    def genid():
        uid = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6]
        if Images.objects.filter(uid=uid).exists():
            uid = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6]
        return uid
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=genid, editable=False)
```

But normally these are defined *outside* the function, for example:

```
def genid():
    uid = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6]
    while Images.objects.filter(uid=uid).exists():
        uid = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6]
    return uid

class Images(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=genid, editable=False)
```

You probably should replace the `if` with a `while` loop, since right now it is still possible that the second attempt fails as well.

Comment: but I'm getting a new error `Images matching query does not exist.`

Comment: @Moswers: you need to use `.filter(..).exists()`. If you use `.get(..).exists()` it will indeed raise an error.